# get and display attached image from google calendar event on website with fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, google-calendar-api

I have imported events from google calendar with fullcalendar on my website. I need display attached image file from google calendar in popup on click to the calendar event.
I trying get image from event object like this `$j('#test-img').html(event.attachment[0].fileUrl);`
but on click I have redirected to google event details page. Another event info are normally displayed.
How can I get correct img url?
Maybe exist google calendar / fullcalendar function to display attached img file from google calendar.

```
    $j('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        googleCalendarApiKey: 'AIzaSyCD7ju2cVMfoM-yLL5IsH3fG9SDUOexjH0',
        events:'jetme6103iige9dqvd7pejpt34@group.calendar.google.com',
        firstDay: 1,
        timeFormat: 'MMMM',
        height: "auto",

        eventClick: function(event) {
            PopUpShow();
            $j('#title').html(event.title);
            $j('#start').html(moment(event.start).format("DD MMMM YYYY"));
            $j('#test-desc').html(event.description);
            $j('#test-img').html(event.attachment[0].fileUrl);
            console.log(event);
            return false;
        },
        loading: function(bool) {
            $j('#loading').toggle(bool);
        },
        eventRender: function(event, element) {
            var dataToFind = moment(event.start).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
            $j("td[data-date='" + dataToFind + "']").addClass('activeDay');
        }
    });
```

Comment: The attachment appears to be only available by following the link to the calendar event - not in the event object itself. You may wish to remove your API key from the code...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can be done through API, you can attach event from calendar UI as this is [Experimental Feature](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/154174?hl=en).